# Pretty URL server side configuration?

Tags: php, apache-2.4, web-server, .htaccess

I have transferred a website to our new VPS. It worked fine on the old server. I think I know what is causing the problem but don't know where to fix it.

I've read a lot of the posts about pretty URLs and it seems most of them are using a mod_rewrite solution. Looking at my `.htaccess` file, it isn't setup that way. It may not even be Pretty URL's at all and called something else entirely.

Our VPS is running WHM/Cpanel

Server Version:

> Apache/2.4.25 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
>
> Apache 2.4, PHP 5.5, PHP 5.6, and PHP 7.0
>
> CENTOS 7.3 x86_64 virtuozzo – server  WHM 62.0 (build 16)

I've run into a problem with the URLs and `.htaccess`.

Here is the contents of the current `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -All SymLinksIfOwnerMatch MultiViews
#AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
DirectoryIndex index
```

When I go to the website I get:

> **Internal Server Error**
>   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>   Please contact the server administrator at webmaster to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>   Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.*

When I remove everything in the `.htaccess` file then the website comes up, but when I click on a link it says it's not found. (In the code it doesn't use the `.php` extension so it doesn't find the page.)

The way it works on the old server is the `.php` extension is not used. So instead of `http://www.example.com/make01.php` it is just `http://www.example.com/make01`.

So I think there is something I have to add to the configuration to make it work the same way it worked on the old VPS. I have access to both VPS's and have looked at the `PHP.ini` files but not entirely sure what I'm looking for.

If you could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

Please let me know if you need any more information. This is my first time posting. Great community by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Options -All SymLinksIfOwnerMatch MultiViews
> ```

Remove the `-All` parameter:

```
Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch MultiViews
```

As noted in the [Apache docs for Apache 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options):

> Mixing Options with a + or - with those without is not valid syntax and will be rejected during server startup by the syntax check with an abort.

Which would seem to be what's happening here. The `-All` parameter is unnecessary since you are explicitly setting just `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` and `MultiViews`. On Apache 2.2 (the old server I assume) this would have simply resulted in "unexpected results" and no error.

> So I think there is something I have to add to the configuration to make it work the same way it worked on the old VPS.

It looks like you are taking advantage of `MultiViews`, so you should be good to go. With `MultiViews` enabled (part of mod_negotiation), a request for `http://www.example.com/make01` will result in the server *searching* for an appropriate file that matches the requested *basename* and required mime-type and serve that to the client. eg. `/make01` results in `/make01.php` being served.

Note that if you later decided to use mod_rewrite to do this URL rewriting then you would probably need to disable `MultiViews` as it might conflict (a common cause of error).

> It may not even be Pretty URL's at all and called something else entirely.

Regardless of how it is implemented, it's still a form of "pretty URLs". It's just making the URLs more friendly (or "pretty") for the user.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, these are still a form of "pretty URLs", regardless of how it's implemented (I've updated my answer regarding that last point).